# PHP Error trying to strip .txt content using fopen

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file = fopen ("test.txt","r");
$string = 'server-port: ';
$result = explode(': ', $file)[1];
echo $result;
fclose( $file );
?>
```

Hello, I'm getting this error below, can you help me? Thanks!

```
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string
```

content file: https://pastebin.com/CzrQchge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) return a `resource` and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) expects an `string` as second parameter.

To read your file contents you should use [`stream_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) with your resource as first parameter:

```
<?php
$stream = fopen ("test.txt","r");
$fileContent = stream_get_contents($stream);
$string = 'server-port: ';
$result = explode(': ', $fileContent)[1];
echo $result;
fclose( $stream );
?>
```

**Edit 1:**

As @MikeVelazco said, [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will eliminate the necessity to use `fopen()` and `fclose()` functions since it operates directly with the file path.

```
<?php
$fileContent = file_get_contents("text.txt");
$string = 'server-port: ';
$result = explode(': ', $fileContent)[1];
echo $result;
?>
```

**Edit 2:**

Since the OP said on comments that need to grab the server-port from the file, I'm suggesting this solution:

Use the following regex: `/server-port=(\d+)/gm` ( you can check it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/F8b43s/1)).

To work with regex you can use the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) function:

```
<?php
$fileContent = file_get_contents("text.txt");
$matches = [];

if (preg_match('/server-port=(\d+)/m', $fileContent, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[1];
} else {
  echo "Server port not found in configuration file";
}
?>
```

You can see it working [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f05a6d9f9cfdb42492e8936c47c96ae88186e485)

Comment: almost the same, but `fread()` expects a `$length` parameter. It's more complicated since you will need to loop until you get `feof($stream)` (indicates that a [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) was received from the stream)

Comment: also `stream_get_contents()` allow to specify a offset (not util on this case)

Comment: Undefined offset: 1 on line 5

Comment: @spycode please post the content of your file. looks like it's not compatible with your `explode()` logic. The "undefined offset" in your case means that the explode didn't found the delimiter `: ` (with whitespace after `:`). Posting your file content will help us to identify the problem

Comment: You file doesn't contains any `:`, so it won't split. Your `explode` will return an array with a single item (index zero) with your entire file as string.

Comment: What are you trying to fetch from this file?

Comment: Eeeh my mistake, but I changed the : to = and still getting erros, do you know to how only capture the "25565" from server-port?

Comment: @spycode I've added a third solution, please test it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use fopen to get the contents, just use `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php 
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$result = explode(':',$file)[1];
echo $result;
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion. Returns empty array

Comment: @spycode It's because the `explode`, not `file_get_contents`. All that I have to add, is that this is the most simple way to extract file content. If you are reading small files (when reading files they store in RAM), this the way.